# UITableViewCell custom separator disappear during scroll ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

i've searched but i haven't found a solution to this, i have a tableview with uitableviewcell. To the cell i need to apply this custom separator:

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, self.contentView.frame.size.height, 80, 1)];

lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.contentView addSubView:lineView];
```

and the separator is displayed correctly, now, i don't know why if i scroll medium fast up and down tableview, the separator disappear on certain cell. I tried to set by:

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, self.contentView.frame.size.height, 80, 1)];

    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    [self.contentView addSubview:lineView];
}
```

any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Did you try UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, self.contentView.frame.size.height - 1, 80, 1)]; ?

Comment: do not  add any subviews in `layoutSubviews` method, add the view during initialisation and set its frame in `layoutSubviews `

Comment: @ArbenPnishi thanks i think setting self.contentView.frame.size.height - 1 solved my problem! didn't thought about frame height!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layoutSubviews` method is wrong place to add subviews, because it calls many times. Add this subview in `awakeFromNib` method.

Also it seems that your line out of cell, because you are using `self.contentView.frame.size.height` try `self.contentView.frame.size.height - 1`

Moreover try to test it on device, sometimes simulator has similar graphic bugs.

Answer (score 0):

u haven't shown any code about how u are creating the cell but i will give a sample example u can do like it, for example

```
//during initialisation
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if(self)
  {
      [self setUpCell]; 
  }
  return self;
} 

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   [self setUpCell];
}

//hear add the views only once 
- (void)setUpCell
{
  //hear add the all views
  UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, self.contentView.frame.size.height - 1, 80, 1)];
  lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  lineView.tag = 123; //set its tag to access it in "layoutsubviews"
  [self.contentView addSubview:lineView];    
}

//this method may be called repeatedly, just set the frames of the subviews hear 
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   UIView *lineView = [self.contentView viewWithTag:123]; //get the subview with tag
   lineView.frame = CGRectMake(90, self.contentView.bounds.size.height - 1,self.contentView.bounds.size.height - 1, 1);
}
```